# when ever i click the menu the event listen from uiloader and text field.I would like to remove event listener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

```
package com
{


    public class gallery_folio extends MovieClip
    {
        var image_xml:XML;
        var xml_loader:URLLoader;
        public var text_style:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana",10,0x333333,"",null,null,null,null,"left");
        public var _style:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana",11,0x333333,"",null,null,null,null,"left");

        public function gallery_folio()
        {
            xml_loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("xml/gallery_folio.xml"));
            xml_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xml_loaded);
        }
        public function xml_loaded(e:Event):void
        {
            image_xml = new XML(e.target.data);
            var menu_mc:MovieClip;
            var menu_uldr:UILoader;
            var label_:TextField;
            for (var i=0; i<image_xml.children().length(); i++)
            {
                menu_mc=new MovieClip();
                menu_mc.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff,1);
                menu_mc.graphics.lineStyle(0.25,0xcccccc);
                menu_mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,70);
                menu_mc.graphics.endFill();
                addChild(menu_mc);
                menu_uldr=new UILoader();
                menu_uldr.source = image_xml.children()[i]. @ img;
                menu_uldr.width = 100;
                menu_uldr.height = 70;

                menu_mc.addChild(menu_uldr);
                menu_mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 15;
                menu_mc.x = 10 + 120 * i;
                menu_mc.buttonMode = true;
                menu_mc.name = image_xml.children()[i]. @ name;
                menu_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onclick_menu);

                label_=new TextField();
                label_.text = image_xml.children()[i]. @ name;
                menu_mc.addChild(label_);
                label_.selectable = false;
                label_.setTextFormat(text_style);


            }

        }
        public function onclick_menu(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(e.target.name);
        }

    }

}
```

the output is based on the xml which structures the data .

```
    <item img="img/img_1.jpg" name="websites">


        <subitem name="m1">
        <image></image>
        <link>http://dasmenonphotography.com</link>
        <description></description>
        </subitem>

        <subitem name="-n-">
        <image></image>
        <link>http://auctussolutions.com</link>
        <description></description>
        </subitem>
    </item>

    <item img="img/img_2.jpg" name="paintings">


        <subitem name="-n-">
        <image></image>
        <link>http://dasmenonphotography.com</link>
        <description></description>
        </subitem>

        <subitem name="-n-">
        <image></image>
        <link>http://auctussolutions.com</link>
        <description></description>
        </subitem>

    </item>

    <item img="img/img_3.jpg" name="paintings">


        <subitem name="-n-">
        <image></image>
        <link>http://dasmenonphotography.com</link>
        <description></description>
        </subitem>

        <subitem name="-n-">
        <image></image>
        <link>http://auctussolutions.com</link>
        <description></description>
        </subitem>

    </item>
</showcase>
```

when ever i click the menu .the event listen from uiloader and text field.I would like to remove event listener from above.Actually i want to create xml gallery .with lots of images

Comment: Hello, Akhil.  This site is intended as a resource for people, that's why it has the question & answer format.  This is a BAD question, because it does not ask anything (there is NO question!) and instead just floods the page with lots of code.  You might get your code fixed this way, if someone actually bothers to read it all, but it sure won't help anyone else.  Please consider re-writing it to be more precise and more helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is to be able to:

1. listen for an event dispatched on an instance by adding an eventlistener, and
2. remove that eventlistener from the clicked target

You can get a reference to the clicked target by using "currentTarget" which references the instance clicked (and not the specific element that was clicked on, which would be "target").

You can remove the eventlistener by calling [the "removeEventListener" method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#removeEventListener%28%29) which takes as an argument the event type, and the event method to remove.

For your case, here is what would solve the problem:

```
   public function onclick_menu(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onclick_menu);
   }
```

Comment: A bunch of code with no explanation does not a good answer make.  Since this is a bad question, a missing explanation might not matter to many people.  But you should consider adding one, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I went into more detail.

Comment: And you've earned a +1 for that :)